# Trouble with a PUT request not updating the entry using MongoDB, Node and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using the MERN stack and cannot get the PUT request to, in this case, update the patient information.

Patient routes- patient.js

```
//@route   POST api/patients
//@desc    Create patient profile
//@access  Private, patient information
router.post('/', [ auth,
    check('firstName', 'First Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
    check('lastName', 'Last name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
    check('medicalConditions', 'Medical Conditions are required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
    ], 
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const {
            firstName,
            lastName,
            dateOfBirth,
            phoneNumber,
            email,
            medicalConditions
        } = req.body

        //Build patient object
        const patientFields = {}
        if(firstName) patientFields.firstName = firstName;
        if(lastName) patientFields.lastName = lastName;
        if(dateOfBirth) patientFields.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        if(phoneNumber) patientFields.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        if(email) patientFields.email = email;
        if(medicalConditions) {
            patientFields.medicalConditions = medicalConditions.split(',').map(medicalCondition => medicalCondition.trim());
        }

        try {
            patient = new Patient(patientFields);
            await patient.save();
            res.json(patient)
        } 
        catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server Error in Create/Update Patient');
        }
    }
);

//@route   GET api/patients/:patient_id
//@desc    Get patient by ID
//@access  Private, patient information
router.get('/:patient_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const patient = await Patient.findById(req.params.patient_id);

    if(!patient) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This patient does not exist." });
    }
    res.json(patient)
} 
catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    if(err.kind == 'ObjectId') {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Patient not found' })
        }
    res.json(500).send({ msg: 'Server Error in get patient by user ID' })
    }
});

//@route   PUT api/patients/:patient_id
//@desc    Update patient information
//@access  Private, patient information
router.put('/:patient_id', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        let patient = await Patient.findById(req.params.patient_id); 

        if(patient) {
            patient = await Patient.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.patient_id, 
                { 
                    firstName: req.body.firstName,
                    lastName: req.body.lastName,
                    dateOfBirth: req.body.dateOfBirth,
                    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    medicalConditions: req.body.medicalConditions 
                }
            );
        }
        return res.json(patient);
    } 
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error in update patient info')
    }
});
```

I've been referencing a tutorial for this project but in the tutorial, the create profile route also updated the profile because it was referencing the id of the logged-in user.

When I test this with Postman I am sending in the patient_id in the url of the patient I want to update and it's sending back the information of a different patient in the db.

How do I modify the put request to update the patient information?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Yes, it did the trick! I appreciate the link to the documentation. The { new: true } makes sense now when re-reading it. Thanks!

Comment: @SuleymanSah Realized that when I update the patient info, the fields that I didn't modify are returning as null. From researching, I think it's something to with the callback. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe they are really null in collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mongoose `findOneAndUpdate`  returns the original document, if you want to return the updated document you need to pass { new: true} in options.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Also your query parameter must be like this:  `{_id:req.params.patient_id}`

So your put route must be:

```
router.put("/:patient_id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let patient = await Patient.findById(req.params.patient_id);

    if (patient) {
      patient = await Patient.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.patient_id },
        {
          firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName,
          dateOfBirth: req.body.dateOfBirth,
          phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
          email: req.body.email,
          medicalConditions: req.body.medicalConditions
        },
        { new: true }
      );
    }
    return res.json(patient);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error in update patient info");
  }
});
```

Another solution is to use `findByIdAndUpdate` which is shorter.
Also it is a good practice to return 400-Bad request (or 404 not found) in case no doc found.
(As you did in your get route)

```
router.put("/:patient_id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let patient = await Patient.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.patient_id,
      {
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        dateOfBirth: req.body.dateOfBirth,
        phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
        email: req.body.email,
        medicalConditions: req.body.medicalConditions
      },
      { new: true }
    );

    if (!patient) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This patient does not exist." });
    }

    return res.json(patient);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error in update patient info");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You either never find the patient, or have errors updating. Try doing a .then & .catch on your update function and see any errors being thrown.